# How can I do AND BIT OPERATOR between two varbinary fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can someone suggest a good solution to this approach.

I have 2 binary strings (1010101....) of 1024 bits in length

Now I would want to do bit operation (AND) on both to get a value whether it is greater than 0 or not.

Currently I am converting the string to hex(256) and varbinary(128)

So once I have two varbinary I am converting 8 bytes of it to BIGINT on each and doing AND on the two BIG INT.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach in SQL 2012.

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: I think that your approach or a user-defined function may be the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long discussion I have finally figured out what input data you have. You have a varbinary(128) that is constructed from a binary string (like '1000010010101... ') that is 1024 characters long. SQL Server does not provide a ready function that does such a conversion. I have built one to allow me testing. The following function does such conversion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.binStringToBinary(@inputString VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS VARBINARY(128) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @inputBinary VARBINARY(128) = convert(varbinary, '', 2)
    DECLARE @octet int = 1
    DECLARE @len int
    SET @len = Len(@inputString)
    while @octet < @len
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @i int = 0
        DECLARE @Output int = 0
        WHILE(@i < 7) BEGIN
            SET @Output = @Output + POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(@inputString, @octet + @i, 1) AS int) * 2, 7 - @i)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
        SET @Output = @Output + CAST(SUBSTRING(@inputString, @octet + @i, 1) AS int)
        select @inputBinary = @inputBinary + convert(varbinary(1), @Output)
        -- PRINT substring(@inputString, @octet, 8) + ' ' + STR(@Output, 3, 0) + ' ' + convert(varchar(1024), @inputBinary, 2)
        SET @octet = @octet + 8
    END
    RETURN @inputBinary
END
```

I then have written a function that checks for a bit using the varbinary(128) as an input:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](@bitToCheck INT,@inputBinary VARBINARY(1024))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @bitToCheck < 1 OR @bitToCheck > 1024
        RETURN 0

    DECLARE @byte int = (@bitToCheck - 1) / 8
    DECLARE @bit int = @bitToCheck - @byte * 8
    DECLARE @bytemask int = POWER(2, 8-@bit)
    SET @byte = @byte + 1

    RETURN CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, CONVERT(binary(1), SUBSTRING(@inputBinary, @byte, 1), 2)) & @bytemask = @bytemask THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END
```

As a bonus, I have also included here a function that does the bit check from a input binary string(1024):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinString](@bitToCheck INT,@inputString VARCHAR(1024))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @bitToCheck < 1 OR @bitToCheck > 1024
        RETURN 0

    RETURN CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@inputString, @bitToCheck, 1) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END
```

Check the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be81a/4) that demonstrates their usage.

```
DECLARE @inputBinary VARBINARY(128)
select @inputBinary = dbo.binStringToBinary('1010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101101000100010111101011101010000110100010001011110101110101000010110100010001011110101110101000011010001000101111010111010100001011010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101101000100010111101011101010000110100010001011110101110101000010110100010001011110101110101000011010001000101111010111010100001011010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101101000100010111101011101010000110100010001011110101110101000010110100010001011110101110101000011010001000101111010111010100001011010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101101000100010111101011101010000110100010001011110101110101000010110100010001011110101110101000011010001000101111010111010100001011010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101101000100010111101011101010000110100010001011110101110101000010110100010001011110101110101000011010001000101111010111010100001011010001000101111010111010100001101000100010111101011101010000101')
select dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1, @inputBinary) bit1,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](2, @inputBinary) bit2,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](3, @inputBinary) bit3,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](4, @inputBinary) bit4,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](5, @inputBinary) bit5,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](6, @inputBinary) bit6,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](7, @inputBinary) bit7,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](8, @inputBinary) bit8,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1017, @inputBinary) bit1017,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1018, @inputBinary) bit1018,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1019, @inputBinary) bit1019,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1020, @inputBinary) bit1020,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1021, @inputBinary) bit1021,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1022, @inputBinary) bit1022,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1023, @inputBinary) bit1023,
       dbo.[DoBitsMatchFromBinary](1024, @inputBinary) bit1024


| bit1 |  bit2 | bit3 |  bit4 |  bit5 |  bit6 | bit7 |  bit8 | bit1017 | bit1018 | bit1019 | bit1020 | bit1021 | bit1022 | bit1023 | bit1024 |
|------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| true | false | true | false | false | false | true | false |    true |   false |   false |   false |   false |    true |   false |    true |
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses...I meanwhile ended up changing my approach slightly...So now what I get is a varbinary(128) and an int(range 1-1024). The Int dictates basically the position that it needs to be checked for a ON(1) in the varbinary....This is what I have implemented but is a bit on the slow end can someone help me on this.I have created a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14203

Comment: What is the source for your binary number? Is it still a varchar(1024) or varbinary(128)?

Comment: see my updated answer. The @bitTocheck takes a value from 0 to 1023 and the function checks the if bit is 1 or 0

Comment: The problem is I have hex string coming in as varbinary(128) not the (1024)bits. So this function fails because of it.Something like this is my input ex has one bit set to hex eight 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: why does it fail? Check the sqlfiddle. I convert the binary string to hex and then pass it to the function. the input string is exactly 1024 bit long, I have checked in Notepad++

Comment: Please do this for me. Run this in the SQL Query: select @hex, convert(varchar(1024, @hex) for your hex string and post to the PasteBin the input hex and the resulting string

Comment: This works ...select convert(varchar(1024), REPLICATE('0',225)+ '8' + REPLICATE('0',30)) but this fails select convert(varchar(1024), REPLICATE('0',225)+ '8' + REPLICATE('0',30))
DECLARE b1 VARBINARY(128);
SET b1 = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), REPLICATE('0',225)+ '8' + REPLICATE('0',30), 2);
select convert(varchar(1024), b1)

Comment: It worked my bad needed to use style 1 in convert,  select b1,convert(varchar(1024), b1,1)...Thanks it is working fine now....

Comment: dbo.[DoBitsMatch](129, @inputBinary) will fails as binary string to varbinary(128) litreally takes each 1 or 0 as one character.

Comment: I still insist you put a string and the varbinary equivalent to the pastebin to know what kind of data we have to deal with. Otherwise, it is not really clear what to do

Comment: OK, I have just tested it in the SSMS's Query analyser. Please note that you must set the maximum number of characters displayed in the results in order to display long string. I set it in mine to display 1024. Anyway, what I found is that in order for the varbinary to hold a 1024 characters long string the length of the varbinary must also be 1024 (when using CONVERT function). It looks like that your varbinary string is constructed by taking 8 bits from the string and converting them each to a byte. CONVERT function will not work in this case

Comment: OK, there you go. It was tough, but doable

Comment: Thanks for all the help really appreciate it....marked your solution as the Answer

Comment: downwote: how does this answer the question?
You provided function to convert from binary string to varbinary value, but the question was about BITWISE operators ove such strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) to split the strings. Compare using [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and check if you get any rows back.

```
declare @s1 char(1024) = '01100100001',
        @s2 char(1024) = '00000100001';

if exists (
          select substring(@s1, N.Number, 1) as C,
                N.Number
          from Numbers as N
          where N.Number between 1 and 1024 and
                substring(@s1, N.Number, 1) = '1'
          intersect
          select substring(@s2, N.Number, 1) as C,
                N.Number
          from Numbers as N
          where N.Number between 1 and 1024 and
                substring(@s2, N.Number, 1) = '1'
          )
begin
  select 'YES'
end
else
begin
  select 'NO'
end;
```

The query plan you get will be quite efficient and will terminate early when you have a match:

[image]

The top Clustered Index Seek will scan the numbers table from 1 to 1024 with a residual predicate checking if `@s1` has a `1` in each position. For each `1` found it will do a seek in the other reference to the numbers table to see if there also is a `1` in that position in `@s2`. When a match is found the execution will stop.

Answer (score 1):

> If your binary numbers can convert to any numeric types this answer can help you.

**& (Bitwise AND) (Transact-SQL)**
Performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.

```
expression & expression
```

**expression**
Is any valid expression of any of the data types of the integer data type category, or the bit, or the binary or varbinary data types. expression is treated as a binary number for the bitwise operation.

> **Note:**
>   In a bitwise operation, only one expression can be of either binary or varbinary data type.

...
You can cast one of expressions to a type like `bigint` if it's possible.

```
declare @b1 varbinary(max) = 0x2, @b2 varbinary(max) = 0x3

print Cast(@b1 & cast(@b2 as bigint) as varbinary(max))
```

Result is:

```
0x0000000000000002
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses...I meanwhile ended up changing my approach slightly...So now what I get is a varbinary(128) and an int(range 1-1024). The Int dictates basically the position that it needs to be checked for a 1 in the varbinary....This is what I have implemented but is a bit on the slow end can someone help me on this .....