# Alternative to bitwise operations in SQL Server >> with more then 62 bits in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have script on my SQL with recursive for example:

```
  WITH recursive bits AS (
        SELECT 0 AS idx
        UNION ALL
        SELECT idx + 1 AS idx
        FROM bits
        WHERE bits.idx + 1 < 64)

select power(2,idx) , idx
from bits
WHERE (9223372036854775808 >> bits.idx & 1) = 1
```

But now I need to convert it into SQL Server

I know about function "power"

```
    WITH  bits AS (
        SELECT 0 AS idx
        UNION ALL
        SELECT idx + 1 AS idx
        FROM bits
        WHERE bits.idx + 1 < 63
        
    )
select *
from bits
where floor(4611686018427387904/power( cast(2 as bigint) ,idx)) & 1 = 1
```

but I need convert power(2,idx) to power(cast(2 as float), idx)  where power> (2,62) - and after that operator "&" doesn't work. Because its working only with int types.

Comment: Bitwise ops isn't really a good fit for SQL's strengths. Separate "facts" should be stored as *separate* pieces of data, not all crammed into a single value which is completely opaque to the system, cannot be indexed, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do AND BIT OPERATOR between two varbinary fields in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337839/how-can-i-do-and-bit-operator-between-two-varbinary-fields-in-sql)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its great idea to change type of stored information, but i have what i have, i need only change sql system from my sql to ms sql.

Comment: What is the range you need, i.e. how many bits? If it exceeds 64-bits (`BigInt`) then what data type will you use since SQL Server cannot represent it as a _numeric_ data type?

Comment: I need to used up to 160 bit line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time and trying found any decision.
Final version - we will use varbinary(20) for this line.

Very helps with it topic:   [How can I do AND BIT OPERATOR between two varbinary fields in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337839/how-can-i-do-and-bit-operator-between-two-varbinary-fields-in-sql)
function [DoBitsMatchFromBinary]
But in that version we have line where bits are going from left to right. i have different bit - line:

pre-info:

Big endian

```
1 byte  7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0 
2 byte  15|14|13|12|11|10|9|8
3 byte  23|22|21|20|19|18|17|16
..
```

or little endian

```
3 byte  23|22|21|20|19|18|17|16
2 byte  15|14|13|12|11|10|9|8
1 byte  7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0 
  ..
```

example(mysql):

```
WITH RECURSIVE bits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS idx
    UNION ALL
    SELECT idx + 1 AS idx
    FROM bits
    WHERE bits.idx + 1 < 160)
SELECT *
FROM bits
WHERE (4611686018968453378 >> bits.idx & 1) = 1;
```

calculating from right to left
bits = 1  (1,8,22,29,62)

0x0201402000000040 (big endian)

0x4000000020400102 (little endian)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DoBitsMatchFromBinaryFromBytes](@bitToCheck INT,@inputBinary VARBINARY(1024))
    RETURNS BIT
        AS
    BEGIN
 
        DECLARE @byte int = (@bitToCheck) / 8
        DECLARE @bit int = @bitToCheck - @byte * 8
        DECLARE @bytemask int = POWER(2, 8-@bit)
        SET @byte = @byte + 1
    
        RETURN floor(CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@inputBinary, @byte, 1), 2)/power( cast(2 as bigint),@bit)) & 1 
    END
```

Its help me with return from "big endian" varbinary correct numbers of bits:

example(mssql):

```
WITH  bits AS (
        SELECT 0 AS idx
        UNION ALL
        SELECT idx + 1 AS idx
        FROM bits
        WHERE bits.idx + 1 < 160)
    SELECT *
    FROM bits
    WHERE [dbo].[DoBitsMatchFromBinaryFromBytes](bits.idx,0x0201402000000040) = 1
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 160);
```

If someone can improve this version, it's will be great.
And I'm hope its can help too.